# Echo topic from a docker container from another machine in the same network

Tags: ros, ros2, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just came back to ROS after a long while and now I'm learning ROS2.
My objective is simply to echo or see a topic broadcasted inside a docker container from Machine 1 to Machine 2.
Machine 1 and Machine 2 are both in the same network. Some basic things I tried is adding the parameter of `--net=host` to spin up my docker container like the following:

**Machine 1:**

`$ docker run -it  --name ros2_container --net=host ros_foxy_image`

**Inside the container:**

`$ source /opt/ros/foxy/install/setup.bash`

`ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker`

**Machine 2:**

`$ source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash`

I expect to at least see `/chatter` from using
`ros2 topic list` however I only see `/parameter_events` and `/rosout`

**Some context:**

Machine 1 is a jetson_nano and I installed the foxy docker image as stated in their repos.

Machine 2 is running on a Ubuntu 20 VM with foxy installed from the debian package.

I can see the topics being broadcasted from Machine 1 just fine but I can't see the topics from Machine 2.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/375957/echo-topic-from-a-docker-container-from-another-machine-in-the-same-network/) by [J. J.](https://answers.ros.org/users/37271/j.-j./) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2021-04-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This was mainly due to the network of the VM connected to NAT. The fix was to enable a Bridge connection to enable the VM to be seen as a physical machine.
Using the settings in VirtualBox the fix was simply:
Settings -> Network -> Change to Bridge.

---

Originally posted by [J. J.](https://answers.ros.org/users/37271/j.-j./) with karma: 60 on 2021-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1